# Using preg_replace to separate gallery from the_content?

Tags: shortcode, the-content

In a Wordpress theme, I need to separate a gallery from the rest of `the_content.` I think one could do that with get_the_content and preg_replace but it's a little beyond my skill level how to actually implement the solution.

Here are the specifics. There's a gallery that looks like this:

```
 <div class="gallery">
      <section class="clearfix">
            <div class="gallery-row">
         some <figures>
             </div>
      </section>
 </div>
  the rest of the content
```

Is there some way I could get that gallery into a variable and put all the rest of the content in another variable.

Then I could just echo the variables wherever I wanted, right?

Comment: Related [question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/121489/split-content-and-gallery/121508) with different solutions.

Answer (score 6):

The easiest way to do that is to hijack the gallery shortcode (no extra regex needed), store it somewhere and add it to the end.

*Prototype*

```
<?php # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
/**
 * Plugin Name: T5 Move Galleries To End Of Content
 */
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', array ( 'T5_Move_Galleries', 'init' ) );

class T5_Move_Galleries
{
    public static $galleries = array();

    /**
     * Re-order gallery shortcodes and register the content filter.
     */
    public static function init()
    {
        remove_shortcode( 'gallery', 'gallery_shortcode' );
        add_shortcode( 'gallery', array ( __CLASS__, 'catch_gallery' ) );
        // Note the priority: This must run after the shortcode parser.
        add_filter( 'the_content', array ( __CLASS__, 'print_galleries' ), 100 );
    }

    /**
     * Collect the gallery output. Stored in self::$galleries.
     *
     * @param array $attr
     */
    public static function catch_gallery( $attr )
    {
        self::$galleries[] = gallery_shortcode( $attr );
    }

    /**
     * Append the collected galleries to the content.
     *
     * @param  string $content
     * @return string
     */
    public static function print_galleries( $content )
    {
        return $content . implode( '', self::$galleries );
    }
}
```

Comment: What I need, though, is to put the gallery (and content) in a string I can then echo anywhere in the loop. In this case, I want to echo the gallery, then the title and some meta content, then the_content.

Comment: Hm … that's tricky because the shortcode is applied to `the_content`. You could just change the method `print_galleries()` to return the desired result.

Comment: I stumbled upon a way to separate gallery and content, it will only use the first instance of the gallery shortcode though. http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/121489/split-content-and-gallery/121508