# Single post content custom order

Tags: shortcode, the-content

In my post I have a shortcode for [video] than text content. Single post page displays first entry-meta, than title, than content [video] + text. 
What I need is to add some condition in single.php so that the order for display to be [video] ->entry-meta ->title ->text. 
Or maybe there is a function to check if I have [video] shortcode in post to display it first than the title and after rest of the content.
Can anyone please help?

I know that tut but I don't know how to use it in single.php.

```
if(has_shortcode('your_short_code')) {  
    // perform actions here  ... 
    // I want to have: do shortcode [video id] or something like this
}
```

I need an example in single.php

I just want to have in single.php displayed first the [video id]  after meta than Title +Content

OR

```
the_content([with video]);

the_content(without video);
```

Comment: Use the code from [this answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/53684/73), and just set the video to the start of the content.

Answer (score 0):

There's a fast and easy tutorial for writing your own `has_shortcode()` function over at **[WP tuts](http://wp.tutsplus.com/articles/quick-tip-improving-shortcodes-with-the-has_shortcode-function/)**.

Comment: Lone link is [considered a poor answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/faq#deletion) since it is meaningless by itself and target resource is not guaranteed to be alive in the future. Please try to include at least summary of information you are linking to.