# Create Gallery using Custom Post Type and add sum gallery as sub gallery of Main Gallery

Tags: plugins, php

Can any one give some idea how to proceed to create gallery  for custom post type and add some gallery as sub gallery of Main gallery ?
So any one click on Main Gallery than Sub Gallery of that will  display.

Comment: Like, a gallery of galleries? So when a user clicks an image from the "Main Gallery" it takes them to an actual gallery? You could use featured images and a post-type archive.

Comment: Yes @Howdy_McGee. So I have featured image as Cover Image for Gallery and Can you explain about How images added for that gallery directly view in custom meta box instead of their url?    Thanks.

Comment: [How to Create Custom-post type in wordpress](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type#Return_Values) [tag:wordpress]

Comment: @MahavarHitesh I know how to create custom post type.                    OK.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When you look at the [template hierarchy](https://developer.wordpress.org/files/2014/10/wp-template-hierarchy.jpg), you can see that there are archive templates. There's also

```
archive-{$post_type}.php
```

And as attachments of any kind are just a post type of the name `attachment`, you could in theory add a template with the filename of `archive-attachment.php` to your theme and have a n archive of all your attachments.

The problem mostly is:

> Galleries are *just all `attachment` posts* that have the *current* post as `post_parent`.

And that means, that there is no central index of all galleries somewhere. Now you could start looping through *all your posts* and run a (very slow) Regex against the post content as [described in this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/121489/split-content-and-gallery/140431#140431).